# Sonar: Using asterisk in sonar.sources

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've successfully set up Sonar and some smaller projects.
Our setup is a Jenkins master/slave system and a sonar-runner installation on every machine. Now I have to integrate a bigger project to sonar and ran into problems.
The project's directory structure looks like this:

```
basedir
 -build
 -source
  -com.stuff* 
   -src ->(contains sourcecode and should be scanned)
   -lib
  -com.otherstuff* 
   -src ->(contains sourcecode and should be scanned)
   -lib
  -projectname* (this has to be excluded)
  -projectnameUNitTests (this has the unit-tests in it)
  -projectnameEJB/src (this one should be included)
```

How do I set this up correctly? when I set
     sonar.sources = source/**/src
Sonar can't parse the directories...
     sonar.exclusions = projectname*
seems to work fine... what should I do?
There are just to many packages to list them all :/
Also: not all of the directories actually contain a src-subdir

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate multiple sources directory with the 'sonar.sources' property, separated by a comma: sources=../src1/,../src2/

If you want absolutely to use **, please post your properties file and log files. There could be something non coherent with other properties (like sonar.projectbasedir).

Regards